# what happens when consumers have no tasks in the queue when using asyncio.Queue()

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have this script

```
import asyncio
import random

q = asyncio.Queue()


async def producer(num):
    while True:
        await q.put(num + random.random())
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random())

async def consumer(num):
    while True:
        value = await q.get()
        print('Consumed', num, value)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

for i in range(6):
    loop.create_task(producer(i))

for i in range(3):
    loop.create_task(consumer(i))

loop.run_forever()
```

that uses `asyncio.Queue()`

I am running my script forever and produces tasks randomly and adding them to the queue. In the event that there are no tasks to consume in the queue, will this be using cpu for nothing or is it harmless and produces no error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the event that there are no tasks to consume in the queue, will this produce an error?

Since the consumer calls [`get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue.get) to consume the next queued item, if the queue is empty, it will simply wait for the next item to arrive. No CPU will be wasted on the wait, and no error reported - the consumer coroutine will just be suspended until an item is produced, after which it will be immediately woken up. During the wait the event loop is free to run other coroutines, if any.

Comment: Wow thats super effective. I am wondering if the producer can be tied to a messaging software such as rabbit mq or kafka or redis.

Comment: @Gandalf Sure, I believe that's one of the use cases for libraries like [aiokafka](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiokafka) and [aioredis](https://github.com/aio-libs/aioredis).

Comment: In your answer on scheduling https://stackoverflow.com/a/51294509/492293 i was wondering if we can add a scheduled task into the queue and if the async nature of the consumer will accept to process at the exact timestamp .

Comment: @Gandalf I'm not sure what you mean by "add a scheduled task into the queue". A queue is a communication channel between different tasks/coroutines intended for producer-consumer workflows like the one in your question. While a queue may transfer any objects whatsoever, adding a _task_ into it is not meaningful (without context). A task is automatically executed and (re)scheduled by the event loop independently of whether it has been added to a particular user-level queue.

Comment: Thanks for your length answer. I appreciated.