# Making a bot that sends messages at a scheduled date with Discord.py

Tags: python, timer, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot that sends a scheduled message to a specific text channel.
for example at the date of my birthday saying "happy birthday", or also every morning saying "Good morning".
The bot seems to don't work since nothing appears in my text channel.

```py
import discord,random,asyncio,os
from datetime import datetime
from discord.ext import commands

token = '#mytokenhere'
bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

send_time='01:41' #time is in 24hr format
message_channel_id='0000000000000' #channel ID to send images to

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)

async def time_check():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    message_channel=bot.get_channel(message_channel_id)
    while not bot.is_closed:
        now=datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),'%H:%M')
        if now.hour() == 1 and now.minute() == 52:
            message= 'a'
            await message_channel.send(message)
            time=90
        else:
            time=1
        await asyncio.sleep(time)

bot.loop.create_task(time_check())


bot.run('token')
```

Comment: Check out the [tasks extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html).  You basically write a coroutine that gets executed on some interval (e.g. every 24 hours)

Comment: Look at this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292027/how-to-schedule-a-task-in-asyncio-so-it-runs-at-a-certain-date It shows how you can do it with asyncio

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's how you would do something like this using the [`tasks` extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html)

```
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

bot = commands.Bot("!")

target_channel_id = 1234

@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def called_once_a_day():
    message_channel = bot.get_channel(target_channel_id)
    print(f"Got channel {message_channel}")
    await message_channel.send("Your message")

@called_once_a_day.before_loop
async def before():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    print("Finished waiting")

called_once_a_day.start()
bot.run("token")
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you! @Patrick Haugh
How I can set an hour to decide to start to do the loop? (for example, 8 am)
Also, there is a way to use this .loop() with a date in the far future (for example, birthdays)?
Thank you again.

Comment: Calculate the time until 8am in the before_loop and asyncio.sleep that amount of time. You can add a check in the task that checks the day and decides what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to use aiocron.

pip install aiocron

https://github.com/gawel/aiocron

Add below to your bot code before the bot.run(TOKEN)

```py
import aiocron

CHANNEL_ID=1234

@aiocron.crontab('0 * * * *')
async def cornjob1():
    channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    await channel.send('Hour Cron Test')
```

If you are using discord 2.0 Read the docs.
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#asyncio-event-loop-changes

```
from discord.ext import commands
import aiocron

TOKEN = 'YOUR TOKEN'
BOT_CHANNELS = 000000000000000000


# you can also import this from else where. 
class cronjobs():
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot) -> None:
        self.bot = bot

        # print Hello world 20secs. 
        @aiocron.crontab("* * * * * */20")
        async def HelloWorld():
            await bot.get_channel(BOT_CHANNELS).send("Hello World!")


class aBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix='>', help_command=None)

    async def setup_hook(self):
        cron = cronjobs(self)

    async def close(self):
        await super().close()

bot = aBot()
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: I've used this the bot dies after starting it.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Way easier to implement than other solutions, literally worked first try

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this (in case someone stomps on this post):

```
import discord
import os
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
client = discord.Client()    

def seconds_until_midnight():
    now = datetime.now()
    target = (now + timedelta(days=1)).replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    diff = (target - now).total_seconds()
    print(f"{target} - {now} = {diff}")
    return diff

@tasks.loop(seconds=1)
async def called_once_a_day_at_midnight():
    await asyncio.sleep(seconds_until_midnight())
    message_channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    print(f"Got channel {message_channel}")
    await message_channel.send("Your message here")

@called_once_a_day_at_midnight.before_loop
async def before():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    print("Finished waiting")

client = discord.Client()
called_once_a_day_at_midnight.start()
client.run(os.environ['BOT_TOKEN'])
```

Comment: how would this work? you're not awaiting `called_once_a_day_at_midnight` even though it's async ---  i get the error `sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Loop._loop' was never awaited`