# discord.py how to send a message everyday at a specific time

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to create a discord bot that sends 2 messages every day each at a specific time. The following code will make the messages enter a loop and will send a message every 5 seconds for example. How can I set a specific time to send the messages every day, for example, message 1 at 6 pm and message 2 at 10 am.
I found this code [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57634182/13491523), but did not find what I want.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

bot = commands.Bot("$")
channel_id = #Any ID

#Message 1
@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def called_once_a_day():
  message_channel = bot.get_channel(channel id)
  await message_channel.send("test 1")

@called_once_a_day.before_loop
async def before():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    print("Finished waiting")
#Message 2 
@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def called_once_a_day2():
    message_channel = bot.get_channel(channel id)
    await message_channel.send("test 2")

@called_once_a_day2.before_loop
async def before():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    print("Finished waiting")




called_once_a_day.start()
called_once_a_day2.start()

bot.run('token')
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple implementation - Every day, it sleeps until the target time and then sends your message

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")
WHEN = time(18, 0, 0)  # 6:00 PM
channel_id = 1 # Put your channel id here

async def called_once_a_day():  # Fired every day
    await bot.wait_until_ready()  # Make sure your guild cache is ready so the channel can be found via get_channel
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id) # Note: It's more efficient to do bot.get_guild(guild_id).get_channel(channel_id) as there's less looping involved, but just get_channel still works fine
    await channel.send("your message here")

async def background_task():
    now = datetime.utcnow()
    if now.time() > WHEN:  # Make sure loop doesn't start after {WHEN} as then it will send immediately the first time as negative seconds will make the sleep yield instantly
        tomorrow = datetime.combine(now.date() + timedelta(days=1), time(0))
        seconds = (tomorrow - now).total_seconds()  # Seconds until tomorrow (midnight)
        await asyncio.sleep(seconds)   # Sleep until tomorrow and then the loop will start 
    while True:
        now = datetime.utcnow() # You can do now() or a specific timezone if that matters, but I'll leave it with utcnow
        target_time = datetime.combine(now.date(), WHEN)  # 6:00 PM today (In UTC)
        seconds_until_target = (target_time - now).total_seconds()
        await asyncio.sleep(seconds_until_target)  # Sleep until we hit the target time
        await called_once_a_day()  # Call the helper function that sends the message
        tomorrow = datetime.combine(now.date() + timedelta(days=1), time(0))
        seconds = (tomorrow - now).total_seconds()  # Seconds until tomorrow (midnight)
        await asyncio.sleep(seconds)   # Sleep until tomorrow and then the loop will start a new iteration


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.loop.create_task(background_task())
    bot.run('token')
```

Comment: If I made any little mistakes, let me know, not used to this layout and I might've missed a few things

Comment: How can I adapt this to run every week on Wednesday at a specific time?

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a `before_loop` so that the first time it runs it will be on time after that just make the loop every 24 hours. Here is an example.

```py
import asyncio
import datetime as dt


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as")
    print(bot.user.name)
    print("------")
    msg1.start()


# Message 1
@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def msg1():
    message_channel = bot.get_channel(705524214270132367)
    await message_channel.send("test 1")


@msg1.before_loop
async def before_msg1():
    for _ in range(60*60*24):  # loop the whole day
        if dt.datetime.now().hour == 10+12:  # 24 hour format
            print('It is time')
            return
        await asyncio.sleep(1)# wait a second before looping again. You can make it more
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a [Discord-bot] That sends a message at a particular time and until that time comes it will be in a sleep. the code i created is small and easy to understand
**Code:**

```
import discord
from datetime import datetime

client = discord.Client()
token = "" #enter your bot's token and it should be a string
channel_id = #enter your channel id and it should be a integer   

def time_module():
    print("time module in use")
    while True:created
        current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")#hour %H min %M sec %S am:pm %p 
        if current_time == "00:00": # enter the time you wish 
            print("time module ended")
            break

time_module()

@client.event
async def on_ready():

    print("bot:user ready == {0.user}".format(client))
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    await channel.send("message")
    

client.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to figure the time of **now**, and the time that you **schedule**, then every like 10 or fewer minutes you check if the scheduled time meets the now.

check this link to see the DateTime library for python https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now

and check this link to see an example of how to use @tasks.loop (background task)
https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/background_task.py

to get the time of now using the dateTime library

```py
now=datetime.datetime.now() #will store the time of when it is called
#if you want to put specific time:
remindMeAT =datetime.datetime(2021,5,4,17,24)  #year,month,day,hour,min,sec
```

Answer (score 0):

After version `1.1.0` is introduced,  `tasks` module supports scheduling tasks at a specific time. All you need to do is give `datetime` object (  or list of `datetime` objects for multiple specified time ) as `time` argument in task decorator.

You can find detailed information in their API [reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html).

```
import datetime
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

utc = datetime.timezone.utc

# If no tzinfo is given then UTC is assumed.
times = [
   datetime.time(hour=8, tzinfo=utc),
   datetime.time(hour=12, minute=30, tzinfo=utc),
   datetime.time(hour=16, minute=40, second=30, tzinfo=utc)
]

daily_announcement_time = datetime.time(hour=14, tzinfo=utc),


class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.my_task.start()

    def cog_unload(self):
        self.my_task.cancel()

    @tasks.loop(time=daily_announcement_time) # scheduling task runs daily
    async def my_daily_task(self):
        print("My daily task is running!")

    @tasks.loop(time=times) # scheduling on multiple time instances
    async def my_task(self):
        print("My task is running!")
```