# Trigger an event every week at a specific day and time in discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to trigger something every Wednesday at 3:30 UTC on a Discord bot using discord.py. I tried modifying the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66715493/11069998), but couldn't figure out how to get it to run every week instead of every day. I am not very familiar with tasks, so I couldn't get it to work from scratch either.

Comment: Have you considered using a webhook? Then activate that either by a cronjob or an online service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an ideal method but it will work.

Taking my answer from that question, You can make it loop every 7 days but that would start at the start of the bot. Use a `before_loop` to set the starting time for the loop.

```py
import asyncio
import datetime as dt


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as")
    print(bot.user.name)
    print("------")
    msg1.start()


# 7 days => 24 hour * 7 days = 168
@tasks.loop(hours=168)
async def msg1():
    message_channel = bot.get_channel(123)
    await message_channel.send("test 1")


@msg1.before_loop
async def before_msg1():
    # loop the whole 7 day (60 sec 60 min 24 hours 7 days)
    for _ in range(60*60*24*7):  
        if dt.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%H:%M UTC %a") == "03:30 UTC Wed":
            print('It is time')
            return

        # wait some time before another loop. Don't make it more than 60 sec or it will skip
        await asyncio.sleep(30)
```

Docs:

- [tasks.loop](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.loop)
- [before_loop](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.Loop.before_loop)

Comment: Will this start on the first Wednesday after it is run, or will I have to wait until the next week for it to trigger? I'm asking this because I'm trying to test it out but it isn't running. I am replacing `03:30 UTC Wed` with `20:55 UTC Mon` for example, but at 20:55 nothing happens.

Comment: I used `datetime.now` which shows the local time, Changed code to use `utcnow`. You can always `print(dt.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M UTC %a"))` to check what are you getting.