# Variable Problem In My Discord Python Bot

Tags: python, discord, bots

I wanted to make a bot which will send a fact every day (I took some code from there). But there is a problem. My bot sends same message every day. Why it doesn't work properly?

```
import os
import time
import discord
import json
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta
import bilgiler_sözlüğü
from server import server

server()

TOKEN = os.environ['bot_token']
client = discord.Client()
sira = 1

def zaman():
    print("Zaman komutu çalıştırıldı.")
    while True:
        current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
        if current_time == "05:45":
            global sayac
            print("Zaman eşleştirildi.")
            break

zaman()



@client.event
async def on_ready():
  global sira
  print("{0.user}".format(client), "çalıştırıldı.")
  channel = client.get_channel(1001947725635530805)
  try:
    await channel.send(bilgiler_sözlüğü.sözlük[sira])
    sira += 1
  except KeyError:
    await channel.send("Bilgilerim bitti!")
    

client.run(TOKEN)
```

"sira" is the variable which pulls out my dictionary. It must increase day by day. What must I do?

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Can you give more information on what happens. Do you get an exception? Does it not send a message? We can't help you unless you tell us what goes wrong.

Comment: You define variable two times, remove `global sira` line and it should probably work I think.

Comment: `sira` resets to 1 every time you start the program again so that could be the issue. If you have a certain number of facts, you could try using the day of the month or [day of the year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620305/convert-year-month-day-to-day-of-year-in-python) instead

Comment: @MiguelGuthridge my bot sends a message from the dictionary called "bilgiler_sözlüğü". My dictionary is like this:

sözlük = {
  1 : "fact one",
   2: "fact two"
}
And it goes like this. Bot must send fact one in first day and must send fact two tomorrow and it must go like that. But my bot sends fact one everyday. I want to fix that.

Comment: @PatrykSzczepański When I write that code first, I did it without global and it gave error. Now I deleted global again to try, and it gave the same error: 

"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sira' referenced before assignment"

Comment: @Tzane I thought it too but my bot works continuosly. However, your day of the month/year could be a solution too, I will try it. Thank you.

Comment: @Tzane But it cause a new problem. Will the code check the date continously? If I create a `while True` loop, then it sends a lot of messages continously. Should I use a `time.sleep(86400)` ? Is there a better way?

Comment: Hmm, I see. Maybe you could check some other threads on how to send daily messages such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63769685/discord-py-how-to-send-a-message-everyday-at-a-specific-time

Answer (score 0):

My bot is working now. For wonderers, its code:

```
import os
import time
import discord
import json
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta
import bilgiler_sözlüğü
from server import server

server()

TOKEN = os.environ['bot_token']
client = discord.Client()
bugün = datetime.now().strftime("%d:%m")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("{0.user}".format(client), "çalıştırıldı.")
  channel = client.get_channel(1001947725635530805)
  try:
    await channel.send(bilgiler_sözlüğü.sözlük[bugün])
  except KeyError:
      await channel.send("Bilgilerim bitti!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith("/gbbilgi"):
    await message.channel.send("**Günün Bilgisi**, her gün saat 00:00'da kanalınıza bir bilgi gönderen bir bottur.\n\n**Yapıcı:** Ajan Smith#4747")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

server.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread

app = Flask('')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return '<h1>Günün Bilgisi</h1>'

def run():
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)

def server():
    t = Thread(target=run)
    t.start()
#Source: https://gist.github.com/beaucarnes/51ec37412ab181a2e3fd320ee474b671
```