# Discord.py run function in class at specific time

Tags: python, discord, scheduled-tasks, discord.py

How do I run the DiscordClient().announceChallenge() every day at 14:00 with the bot/script running 24/7?

````
imports

class DiscordClient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))
    
    async def announceChallenge(self):)
        print("Announced the daily challenge")

client = DiscordClient()
client.run(token)```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making a bot that sends messages at a scheduled date with Discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57631314/making-a-bot-that-sends-messages-at-a-scheduled-date-with-discord-py)

Comment: @Flair Do you know how I could make the bot run at a specific time instead of just every24 hours or such?

Comment: The comments in the accepted answer suggest various ways to do it. You can calculate when 14:00 will be in the next day and calculate the wait from there.

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs about [the sched module](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sched-module-in-python/).

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html) is a simple tutorial.